# No value for command Working with JSON at Android Kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I'm using a websocket observer that receive `json`, and wrote the below code to deserialize the json object, and check it, but I got the app crashed as `Caused by: org.json.JSONException: No value for command`

The json object I'm receiving is very simple:

```
{"command":"action","action":"test action"}
```

My Kotlin code is:

```
client.message.observe(this@MainActivity, androidx.lifecycle.Observer<String> { s: String? ->

   val reader = JSONObject(s)
   val action = when(reader["command"].toString()) {
                "action" -> reader["action"].toString()
                "notify" -> reader["notify"].toString()
                    else -> "Nothing"
   }
})
```

Comment: Are you really sure that `s` has the value `{"command":"action","action":"test action"}` ? Did you debug this?

Comment: @donfuxx actually it hasn't before returning s, i.e. while s still null/Emory

Comment: @donfuxx actually it hasn't before returning s, i.e. while s still null/Emory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it was due to not getting the correct json in some case, so first I need to check if the json contains the required string or no, an to be in safe side, I'm checking also if it is not empt before reading it, so my code became:

```
if (s!!.isNotEmpty()) {
    reader = JSONObject(s)
    if (reader.has("command")) {
       val action = when(reader["command"].toString()) {
                    "action" -> reader["action"].toString()
                    "notify" -> reader["notify"].toString()
                    else -> "Nothing"
       }
       chaptersList.add(insertIndex, action)
       adaptor.notifyItemInserted(insertIndex)
    }
}
```